# Datetime issue when switching site language CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, php-7.2, cakephp-3.6

I'm working on a CakePHP 3 application and the problem that I'm having right now is that I'm using the PHP date function to display dates in format like "date month year" (for example: 12 Sept 2018) like so:

```
date('d M Y', strtotime(my_mysql_datetime));
```

but the problem is that it works when the website is in english, but when I change the website language to french for example, the datetime format also changes which results in **strtotime** returning **false**.

How can I prevent the datetime that I get from my database to change when I switch the website language?

Comment: Where do you get `my_mysql_datetime` from? If its from an `Entity`, `my_mysql_datetime` should be either a `Cake\I18n\Time` or `Cake\I18n\Date` object which extends PHP `DateTime` where you can call ->format() like so `my_mysql_datetime->format('d M y')`